# Gateway Timeout Error on Insert 70000 record using Hibernate in Java

Tags: java, mysql, excel, hibernate, amazon-ec2

My Problem is:

Upload 10000 Record from Excel To my Database. The Excel Sheet has 10000 Rows and 70 to 100 Column . We Store the Value in 6 Mapping Table using Hibernate cascade.
I call the method using ajax method. Due to inserting large amount of data. it return timeout error(502 (Proxy Error) OR 504 (Gateway Error)).

I am using AWS Services. Is any configuration mistake.. please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I tried Sync and Async callback aslo

Comment: what api do you use exactly to upload your excel file, which service to read it ? you say ajax method, which one ?

Comment: anyway, I have a general strategy for you: split your file into batches (say, csv file could be easily split using some command line tools) and do them one by one.

Comment: jquery ajax method

Comment: upload in batches. find max number you upload at one time, and split your file

Answer (score 0):

How You Might See a 502 Bad Gateway Error

Based on your web server, you might see a different 502 error. These all mean the same thing, it is only their naming conventions that differ. Here are a few examples of what you might see:

“502 Bad Gateway”
“HTTP Error 502 – Bad Gateway”
“502 Service Temporarily Overloaded”
“Error 502”
“502 Proxy Error”
“HTTP 502”
“502 Bad Gateway NGINX”
You can see in greater detail what the error specifically entails by going to your web server’s error log file. All error / diagnostic information is stored in this file making it a valuable resource to check when you need more details about a particular error.  You can locate this file in Apache by going to /var/log/apache2/error.log and in Nginx by going to /var/log/nginx/error.log.

How to solve 502 errors?

Check if your FQDN is resolving correctly by using our DNS test tool.

Verify if your server is reachable by using a ping test or trace-route.

Check your firewall logs if you are seeing unusual drops.

Open a support in the KeyCDN dashboard if you can not solve the 502 problem.

Comment: While i am uploading 100 records, its getting upload. but while uploading bulk rows, the getting error on my browser console